# Retrieving Current location using Google Maps

Tags: cordova, google-maps, geolocation

My code checks current user position and then loads all nearby stores including distance to location using cordova's geolocation plugin.

This is my code:

```
.factory('GSSearchLocationService',['$cordovaGeolocation', '$q',function($cordovaGeolocation, $q){
function _getLocation(options){
    var callStart  = options.callStart;
    var deferred   = options.deferred;
    var attempt    = options.attempt;
    var othOptions = options.othOptions;

    deferred.notify({attempt: attempt, message:'Searching attempt '+attempt, lastAccuracy : options.lastAccuracy});

    var getLocOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: othOptions.gps.enableHighAccuracy,
        timeout: othOptions.gps.timeout * 100,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    var locWatch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(getLocOptions);
    locWatch.then(
       null,
       function(err) {
           locWatch.clearWatch();
           deferred.reject({err:err});
       },
       function(position) {
           var callEnd = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
           locWatch.clearWatch();
           if ( position.coords.accuracy && position.coords.accuracy <= othOptions.gps.accuracy ) {
               // This is good accuracy then accept it
               deferred.resolve({status:0, position:position});
           } else if ( (callEnd - callStart) < othOptions.gps.timeout ) {
             // Keep trying till the configured wait time. If exceeds then return back.
             options.attempt++;
             options.lastAccuracy = Math.round(position.coords.accuracy * 100) / 100;
             options.minAccuracy = options.minAccuracy || options.lastAccuracy; // Default
             options.minAccuracy = options.minAccuracy < options.lastAccuracy ? options.lastAccuracy : options.minAccuracy;
             _getLocationWrapper(options);
           } else {
               othOptions.gps.timeout
               deferred.reject( {error:{code:-999, message:"Could not get location.<br>Most min accuracy is "+options.minAccuracy+" mts.<br>Try to check location in open area or try adjusting to acceptable accuracy."}} );
           }
       }
    );

}


function _getLocationWrapper(options) {
     var locCB=function(){return _getLocation(options);};
     if ( options.attempt == 1 ) {
         locCB();
     } else {
       setTimeout(locCB, options.othOptions.gps.interval*1000);
     }
}

return {

    getCurrentLocation : function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        callStart = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
        _getLocationWrapper({callStart:callStart, deferred:deferred, othOptions:options, attempt:1});
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
  }])
```

It worked fine until a few days ago, when I try to get the current position I get the following error:

```
message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403.
```

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a request limit of 2500 per day.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Another reason could be, that you are using an old API from Google.

If the only thing you need is the geolocation, then use this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation

If you need more things like searching, maps, …, then take this plugin:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

**Update:**

If you use cordova-plugin-googlemaps then it is very easy. From the docs at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map (Get my location):

```
var onSuccess = function(location) {
  var msg = ["Current your location:\n",
    "latitude:" + location.latLng.lat,
    "longitude:" + location.latLng.lng,
    "speed:" + location.speed,
    "time:" + location.time,
    "bearing:" + location.bearing].join("\n");

  map.addMarker({
    'position': location.latLng,
    'title': msg
  }, function(marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
  });
};

var onError = function(msg) {
  alert("error: " + msg);
};
map.getMyLocation(onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I only need the geolocation so that I can be able to place them on a map.

I am also using the latest version of the cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: Let me try your approach. Thanks you so much for taking your time to help, I appreciate wholeheartedly

Comment: I am struggling to get it to work with ionic framework :-(

Comment: Does the cordova-plugin-geolocation is running? Or where is the problem?

Comment: I guess where to initialise. I am loading the map in a controller but keep getting the error that plugin is undefined. Here's a snippet of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/5db0y2cz/