# Cordova google maps plugin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have this the following code to draw map and animate the camera to my current location it working correctly only when i put exact lat & long (exact numbers) but i need to pass the user current location wherever he is, so i need to know how to pass the user current location to this

```
var map;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  // Initialize the map view 
  map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

  // Wait until the map is ready status. 
  map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
}, false);


function onMapReady() {
  // Move to the position with animation 
  map.animateCamera({
    target: {lat: 30.1234567, lng: 31.1234567},
    zoom: 17,
    tilt: 60,
    bearing: 140,
    duration: 5000
  }, function() {

    // Add a maker 
    map.addMarker({
      position: {lat: 30.1234567, lng: 31.1234567},
      title: "Welecome to \n" +
             "Cordova GoogleMaps plugin for iOS and Android",
      snippet: "This plugin is awesome!",
      animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }, function(marker) {

      // Show the info window 
      marker.showInfoWindow();

      // Catch the click event 
      marker.on(plugin.google.maps.event.INFO_CLICK, function() {

        // To do something... 
        alert("Hello world!");

      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on this [tutorial](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map). Use [cordova-geolocation-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) or [Cordova Background Geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt), it works much more stable and has a lot more functions. You can pass the results back to the maps plugin.

```
var onSuccess = function(location) {
  var msg = ["Current your location:\n",
    "latitude:" + location.latLng.lat,
    "longitude:" + location.latLng.lng,
    "speed:" + location.speed,
    "time:" + location.time,
    "bearing:" + location.bearing].join("\n");

  map.addMarker({
    'position': location.latLng,
    'title': msg
  }, function(marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
  });
};

var onError = function(msg) {
  alert("error: " + msg);
};
map.getMyLocation(onSuccess, onError);
```

You may also follow the code given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758678/retrieving-current-location-using-google-maps).